# js add object to object with $or and get [object]

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I try to generate an object with {$or: [{object1}, {object2},...]} to fire a query to mongo, but I always get [object] after assigning to $or. Can somebody help me and tell me what I´m doing wrong. I tried it with creating an own array for the $or[], with a for-loop and so on - always the same. Some ideas?

```
if(req.body.sicDiv) {
    co_sicDiv = {
        $in: sicDiv.split(',')
    };
    query = Object.assign({co_sicDiv: co_sicDiv}, query);
    //works fine,  I get: { co_sicDiv: { '$in': [ 'C' ] }
}
if(req.body.sicMajor) {
    if (sicDiv){
        co_sicMaj = {
            $in: sicMaj.split(',')
        };
        console.log('co_sicMaj: ', co_sicMaj);
        sicMajO =Object.assign(
                    {'co_sicDiv': co_sicDiv},
                    {'co_sicMaj' : co_sicMaj}
                );
        console.log('SicMajO: ', sicMajO);
        //Works fine, I get: SicMajO:  { co_sicDiv: { '$in': [ 'C' ] }, co_sicMaj: { '$in': [ '15', '16' ] } }

        sicMajOR =Object.assign({$or: [
            {'co_sicDiv': co_sicDiv},
            {'co_sicMaj' : co_sicMaj}
            ]}
        );
        console.log('SicMajOR: ', sicMajOR);
        //Doesn´t work, I get: SicMajOR:  { '$or': [ { co_sicDiv: [Object] }, { co_sicMaj: [Object] } ] }
```